# Calculation involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, quantum-field-theory

I am trying to derivethe $N$ defined via the following integral:

$$\displaystyle  \frac{4\pi^2}{\omega N^2}= \int_0^L \frac{dz}{z}
  \left(1-\frac{z^2}{L^2}\right)^{-1} |V_k(z)|^2  $$

where
$$\displaystyle 
  V_k(z) 
=
  \left(\frac{z}{L}\right)^\Delta 
  \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{L^2} \right)^{-iL\omega/2}
  {}_2 F_1\hspace{-4pt}\left[\frac{\Delta-iL\omega +iL k}{2},
    \frac{\Delta-iL\omega-iL k}{2}
    ; \Delta ; \frac{z^2}{L^2}
  \right] .
$$
Here $\Delta,\omega,L,k$ are all real. $\Delta$ and $L$ are positive.

The $V_k(z)$ are real and satisfy $V_{\omega,k}(z) = V_{-\omega,k}(z) = 
  V_{\omega,-k}(z) = V_{-\omega,-k}(z)$.

The correct answer is apparently:

$$  N= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 L |\omega|}}
  \frac{
 \Gamma\left(\frac{\Delta - iL (\omega + k)}{2}\right)
   \Gamma\left(\frac{\Delta - iL (\omega - k)}{2}\right)
  }
  {\Gamma(\Delta)\Gamma(iL \omega)}$$

I want to derive this answer from the above equations. I think this should come down to some identities involving hypergeometric functions. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I don't recognize your equations, but the general solution of the massive field, including the normalization of the continuum modes in the rindler wedge is solved in my old answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418926/solving-the-kg-equation-in-rindler-coordinates/419121#419121).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really a pure mathematics question, even though it's arisen in a physics constant. Would you like it migrated to [math.se]?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: @rob Please migrate it to maths. Thanks.

Comment: Where are these equations from? Did you take them from a book? Could you provide some details?

Comment: @Anatoly Equations 3.14-3.18 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3426.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link. How did you get the first of your equations?

Comment: @Anatoly It follows from 3.13, by substituting the definition of S_k given in the paragraph just above.

Comment: It would be better to provide some basic info about constants involved since this is a math site, for example, are $\omega, L, \Delta, k^1$ real? The paper states (immediately before $3.15$) that $V_k(z)$ is real, this would imply $\omega L, \Delta, Lk^1$ are all real. However, when $\omega L$ is real, your integral diverges (due to singularity at $z=L$). Please make sure you included all details that are mathematically necessary.